# Having a singular subject and a plural object - which form to choose for the verb?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [In special cases, can you use “one such family are” vs. “one such family is”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23685/in-special-cases-can-you-use-one-such-family-are-vs-one-such-family-is)
>   [[Singular] Is/Are [Plural]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/singular-is-are-plural)

I often encounter sentences like

> The best solution *is / are* implicit parameters.

Which form is correct in this case?

Comment: @Alenanno: Thanks. You may close this as a duplicate.