# Which is correct: The rest of the staff is or are? The rest of my family is or are?

Tags: grammatical-number

I hope you can enlighten me. I get varying answers in Google and I need to find out which is the correct grammatical structure for these sentences.

> The rest of the staff is/are on leave at the moment.
>
> The rest of my family is/are arriving late.

Comment: Why are you so sure that just one of them must be "correct"?

Comment: Related: [Is “staff” plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural)

Comment: Related: [In special cases, can you use “one such family are” vs. “one such family is”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23685/in-special-cases-can-you-use-one-such-family-are-vs-one-such-family-is)

Comment: I think those questions already explain both cases quite adequately.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the singular (is) in both examples as we are referring one "staff" and one "family", even though they may consist of many people.

The same can be said for the nouns "team", "company", "organisation" etc.

NB: Edited after Peter's comment

Comment: I would certainly not use the singular (perhaps unless there happened to be only one person, but in that case I would be unlikely to say "the rest of my family")

Comment: This answer may be right, but the reasoning is incorrect. The reason you (and, I believe, most Americans) use the singular in these examples is that you are only referring to one "staff" or "family". Would you say "The rest of the paintings is in storage"?

Comment: Quite right, terrible (or rather just plain wrong) explanation! Staff is an uncountable noun and family is singular. Will edit immediately! Ps. I'm British and not American, but we do (for the most part) use the same grammar!

Comment: @Matt: I would have thought this is one of the areas of grammar where there is a British/American difference. People can say "the government are" and "the staff are" in the U.K., and people generally don't in the U.S.

Comment: Peter and @Matt, I think you have misidentified the subject of the verb. It is not staff or family, but "the rest". See my answer below.

Comment: @Fraser: In my grammar, for "the rest of", as in "a lot of", the verb agrees with the noun following "of". While "rest" is the grammatical subject, it changes number. Consider a shipment of desks. "Half the shipment arrived today. The rest arrives tomorrow." or "Half the desks arrived today. The rest arrive tomorrow." Same shipment, same desks; different verb. The ambiguity here comes from the fact that the nouns "staff" and "family" can take both "is" and "are".

Comment: @Peter: Perhaps you're right that BE publications are more relaxed in allowing the use of "the staff are" or "the team are" than in the US. On a related point, something that often gets people heated is the word "data" - I feel that, although technically correct, "the data are..." simply sounds wrong and prefer "the data is..." - I'm sure that this debate has been had before somewhere on this forum.

Answer (score 3):

This is my opinion. *Family* and *staff* are collective nouns. A collective noun, as we know, may take a singular or plural verb depending on whether we see it as a unit or a collection of individuals. Therefore, if the rest of the family is moving as one, then we can say, "The rest of my family *is* arriving late" (this means the other members of the family are arriving *together*).

Fraser Orr is correct in saying that the subject is the word *rest* but the singularization or pluralization of the verb depends much on the specific noun that follows the abovementioned subeject. Take the following examples.

> - The rest of the apples **are** rotten.
> - The rest of the book **was** burned.

The use of this becomes confusing if the noun that follows is a collective noun.

Answer (score 3):

Either singular or plural can be correct, especially in British English. The reason can be seen in two steps, involving two things which complicate subject-verb agreement: **number-transparent** nouns and **collective nouns** ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), pp. 501-504).

<sup>Let me remind you that the subject is always the whole noun phrase (NP), so in your first example, the subject is the NP *the rest of the staff*, and in your second example, the subject is the NP *the rest of my family*. The question of whether you need the singular *is* or the plural *are* rest on whether the NPs *the rest of the staff* and *the rest of my family* are singular or plural.</sup>

**First step:** note that *rest* is a **number-transparent** noun ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), p. 350). Consider the following examples with another number-transparent noun, *lot*:

[1] a.  *[A lot of work] was done.*
      b.  *[A lot of errors] were made.*

In both [1a] and [1b], the subject (in brackets) is a noun phrase (NP) whose [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) is *lot*. But the number of the NP (i.e. whether the NP is singular or plural) is determined not by the head, as is normally the case, but by the number of the *oblique* (i.e. by the number of the complement of the preposition *of*): *a lot of work* is singular because *work* is singular, and so we have the singular verb *was*. And *a lot of errors* is plural because *errors* is plural, and so we have the plural verb *were*. Besides *lot* and *rest*, there are only several other clear examples of number-transparent nouns: *lots, plenty, bags, heaps, loads, oodles, remainder, number,* and *couple*  (CGEL, p. 350). In the words of CGEL, a number-transparent noun *allows the number of the oblique to percolate up to determine the number of the whole NP* (CGEL, p. 349). In your examples, *the staff* and *my family* are the obliques, and they determine the number of the NPs *the rest of the staff* and *the rest of my family*.

So, because *rest* is number-transparent, the question of whether *the rest of the staff* is singular or plural reduces to the question of whether *the staff* is singular or plural. Similarly for *the rest of my family* and *my family*. And now comes step two.

**Second step:** even though *staff* and *family* are singular, they are **collective nouns,** and as such they allow optional **plural override.** Here is an example (CGEL, p. 501):

[2] a.  *[The committee] **has** not yet come to a decision.*       [simple ageement]
      b.  *[The committee] **have** not yet come to a decision.*        [plural override]

Both [2a] and [2b] are acceptable, especially in British English (in American English, the plural override is less likely). According to CGEL (p. 502),

> The optionality of the override with collectives reflects the fact that there is  potentially a difference of meaning between the versions with singular and plural verbs. From one perspective a committee is a single entity, but since a committee (normally) consists of a plurality of members it can be conceptualised as denoting this plural set. The construction with a plural verb focuses on the members of the committee rather than on the committee as a unit.

Besides *committee, staff,* and *family*, there are other clear examples of collective singular nouns that allow optional plural override (with appropriate verbs), such as *administration, army, board, class* (in one of its meanings), *clergy, crew, enemy,* etc. A list is given in CGEL, p. 503.

In short: in your examples, both the singular verb *is* and the plural verb *are* are acceptable. In the case of *staff*, if you use the plural, you are thinking of *staff* as a set consisting of a plurality of members. True, *staff* is merely the oblique (the complement of *of*), and is not the head of the NP which is the subject of the sentence; rather, *rest* is the head. But *rest* is number-transparent, and so the number of the whole NP is determined by the number of the oblique. And, as we said, the number of the oblique is, through the (optional) plural override, taken to be plural. In contrast, if you use the singular verb, you are thinking of *staff* as a single entity, and now it is this singular number that 'percolates up' to determine the number of the whole NP. The case of *family* works just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since "the rest" is followed by a plural noun for which one might substitute the pronoun "them," and you wouldn't say "the rest of them is late," I vote for "are."

Answer (score 0):

Plural verbs are appropriate here. "Staff" and "family" can both be both mass nouns, and so can take singulars "Steve Jobs' family is mourning his loss", though, a plural can also be acceptable, "His staff are devastated." Nonetheless, the subject of the verb is not "staff" or "family," it is "the rest" with the genitive qualifier ("of the staff/family.") This subject is plural, and requires a plural verb.

```
The rest of the staff are on leave
The rest of the family are arriving late.
```

Answer (score 0):

The subject of each sentence is "the rest".  "Of the staff" and "of my family" are phrases qualifying "the rest".

In the case of "staff" and "family", "the rest" refers to a group of people.  The group of people is countable.

The correct conjugation of "to be" for subjects referring to countables will be "are".

> The rest of the staff are on leave at the moment.

In the case where "the rest" refers to an uncountable entity (e.g. "the rest of the time", "the rest of the meal", etc.), "to be" will be conjugated as "is".

> The rest of the time is yours.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with singular. "Rest" is a collective noun that denotes a group defined by a characteristic. "The rest of the bunch is here."

Comment: Are you sure? “The rest of the players have decided to stay home and not play.”

Answer (score 0):

It is awkward to say, "While some of the family is here, the rest of the family are on their way." Use the same - singular or plural in such a sentence. I have always used singular with nouns like family, team and staff. Plural is reserved for "families" or "teams."

Comment: But *some* is plural, so one would say "While some of the family are here..." and then, presumably *are* again? "While some of the family are here, the rest are on their way."

Answer (score 0):

> [**That** occurs idiomatically in reference to groups (where *who*
> would sound peculiar)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=that)

According to the Ngrams

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What if I take away the quantified item?
Shouldn't the verb should remain the same for consistency?

For instance:

- The rest *of the soldiers* is dead

Would become:

- The rest (...) is dead

Also, what about swapping "rest" for another expression:

- The leader of the ants **is** called the queen.

I would say that "the rest" is the noun, so is always singular, regardless of what it is about, which is only a qualifier.

And by the way, this is how the logic works in French, for what it's worth in English grammar :)

Comment: “The rest of the soldiers is dead” is completely wrong in every context I can possibly think of. _Rest_ may be the grammatical subject, but the verb agrees with the notional subject, which is the qualifier.