# Is this mixture of plural and singular legitimate?

Tags: verb-agreement, collective-nouns, copular-verbs, complements, syntactic-analysis

> But what is most important for our purposes is that these changes were
>   the signal for the resumption of historical debate on a grand scale,
>   of the kind that had been suspended or driven underground during the
>   reign of Louis XIV. （The French Idea of Revolution ed. by Dale Van
>   Kley: 203)

I am interested in the expression "these changes were the signal". Shouldn't every change be a signal, so that there are many signals? Why use the singular form? Because all these changes together form a signal, and one or two just cannot signify that there is a resumption of that debate?

Answer (score 3):

A verb agrees with its subject, not its complement, not even in copulas.

> His **injuries** that day **were** the **start** of his decline.
>
> These **ideas are** a fresh new **way** of looking at the problem.
>
> My **parents are** the only **reason** I bother to go home for Christmas anymore.

Comment: What about 'The start of his decline was/were his injuries.' Which then? Does plural always take precedence?

Comment: @Mitch Your example should read “The **start** of his decline **was** his **injuries”**.  Whittle it down to ***“start was”*** — get it? So it is not that “plural takes precedence”; rather and as déjà dit, **the verb always agrees in grammatical number with its subject *not with its complement.***

Comment: Guys guys guys, there's [a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23685/in-special-cases-can-you-use-one-such-family-are-vs-one-such-family-is) for that. And more questions still linked from there. As far as this question here is concerned, I think the answer is pretty sufficient.