# "Is" with singular and plural nouns

Tags: grammar, british-english, semantics, copular-verbs, be

I came across the sentence

> My biggest grievance is grammar mistakes.

I'd be inclined to write it as

> My biggest grievance is *with* grammar mistakes.

or

> Grammar mistakes are my biggest grievance.

What is the correct way to write this, and why?

Comment: They are all correct. See this related question (asked by none other than myself): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8716/how-do-i-determine-subject-and-subject-complement-in-a-side-effect-is-the-sprea

Comment: Every one of them is correct. 'grammar mistakes' could be considered either as a type of error (singular) or several instances of individual errors (plural).

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate): [<Singular> Is/Are <Plural>?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/singular-is-are-plural)

Answer (score 1):

The verb should be singular or plural based on the subject. In your first and second examples, grievance is your subject, so you use *is*. In the last example, *mistakes* is your subject so you want to use *are*.

Comment: No, this is wrong. As is stated in the comments, all of the options are correct.

Comment: @MattЭллен But doesn't Dymatic say exactly the same thing as you do, although in a more tortous way? Why downvoting him for saying that the three sentences are all correct and that the verb should be the one requested by the subject?

Comment: @Paola, I see, yes. I was confused by the wording.